# Lie algebra of SO(V) is isomorphic to spin(V)

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

[image]

where $a\in Cl^2(V)$, and $\tau(a)(v)=[a,v]$ for $v\in V$. I was wondering is the first equality correct as written? Jost earlier defined the clifford algebra as the quotient of the tensor algebra by ideal generated by the relations $v\otimes v+\|v\|^2=0$, which yields
$$-2\langle v,w\rangle=vw+wv$$
upon polarizing. Back to the computation, I'm computing
$$\langle \tau(a)v,w\rangle=-\frac{1}{2}(\tau(a)vw+w\tau(a)v)$$
while
$$-\frac{1}{2}[[a,v],w]=-\frac{1}{2}[\tau(a)v,w]=-\frac{1}{2}(\tau(a)vw-w\tau(a)v)$$

These differ by a sign. Did I make an error somewhere?

Comment: I don't have Jost's book, but in Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators (Berline, Getzler, Vergne), Clifford algebras are treated as super-algebras. In particular, if $x$ and $y$ are of weight one, $[x,y]= xy + yx$ (i.e., the commutator has a plus sign, e.g., with $x=\tau(a)v$ and $y=w$). Does Jost do the same, so that is the issue here? (FWIW Jost's above lemma is  Prop 3.7 in Heat Ks and...)

Comment: By weight, I assume you mean $x,y\in Cl^1(V)$? Actually the only place I see Jost define a bracket is on $Cl^2(V)$, where it is defined as $[a,b]:=ab-ba$. So your commutator means if the weights of the input are both odd, you get a +; otherwise you have a -?

Comment: "Weight" is probably not used in my reference either... I shouldn't have used it. But yes, you're exactly right: even versus odd, or "parity" (a ${\mathbb Z}/2$ grading).  What is "(1.8.1)" above?.

Comment: That would refer to the equality in my post $-2\langle v,w\rangle =vw+wv$.

Comment: OK... But putting the sign issue aside, are you okay with the equality $$\langle \tau(a)v,w\rangle + \langle v,\tau(a)w\rangle  = 0?$$ That is, skipping the offending commutator use (or notation, as I want to believe) in-between, and doing the manipulation directly? Or would you like it written out? I think I can do that if you like - but that wasn't your question, of course, to which I've already given my best guess that Jost was thinking super algebra / commutator.

Comment: So even before I typed up this question, I did have a way to see the equality, but if possible I'd like to a way to do with the super-commutator way just so I can familiarize myself with it. For example, I'm not even sure if $a,b,c$ are of different weights, if formulas such as the following hold $$[[a,b],c]=-[c,[a,b]]$$

Comment: It's a bit late here so tomorrow I'll try to find the online copy of my reference (it existed once) so that I can point to and you can see the relevant pages. In my edition it would be pages 39 and 105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a follow up on the comment sequence above.

The following are taken from  [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators.](http://www.math.univ-metz.fr/~gnc/bibliographie/DiracOperators/%5bN._Berline_E._Getzler_M._Vergne%5d_Heat_Kernels_and.pdf)

On page 39,

[image: superalgebra definition]

(2) is "the Jacobi identity." To verify it (in the case of a the bracket being the [super]commutator of multiplication), use that the parity of a product is the sum $\pmod 2$ of that of the individual terms:

$$ |a\cdot b| = |a| + |b| $$ (assuming that parity makes sense - i.e., $a$ and $b$ are 'pure').

Next, on page 103,

[image: Clifford Algebra Definition]

Finally, on page 105,

[image: Lie algebra identification]

The reason that $[a,[v,w]] = 0$ is that $[v,w] = vw +wv = -2 Q(v,w)\in {\mathbb R}$, and so in the center.

Comment: I hadn't bothered with the Lie superalgebra formulism = the Jacobi identity when verifying 3.7 (no doubt exactly the way  you did). For instance, I only verified  Jacobi for myself last night - the typos/mathos in the book 'supplement' my own mental limitations, shall we say...

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!